Proving points are collinear.
Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle with $H$ as the orthocenter. Let $AP$ be a diameter of a circle the enclosed the triangle $ABC$ with the center $O$. If $M$ is a point on $BC$ which bisect $BC$ itself, show that $H, M, P$ must be collinear.
(This is not an analytic geometry type question, but more like Euclidean geometry on lines and circles question. The kind of competition problems like https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2013_IMO_Problems/Problem_4)
Firstly, starting drawing something is a must. So I draw it using Geogebra. Here is the question is all about. At least, Geogebra confirms that they must be colinear (though it is definitely not a proof).

Since I am not sure where to start, and this kind of question always need to draw something more, so let say we forget $M$. Now let $M'$ be the intersection of $BC$ and $PH$. This means if I am able to show that $M' = M$, the proof is done.

To do this, I seem to recall that diagonal lines of a parallelogram must bisect each others. So if I show that $BPHC$ is a parallelogram, it is done.
Now here are questions:

To show that $BPHC$ is a parallelogram, it is enough to just prove that $BH // PC$ and $BP // HC$ ? So $PS$ and try to show that the angle $CBF$ is equal to the angle $SPC$. This is quite different from usual analytic geometry that I am used to (like we must know some coordinates, checking slope etc, but here it is nothing ! Just a picture !). Can anyone suggest something here?

I am not sure if what I think is a "good" approach to this. Anyone has a better way/standard way to do this kind of problems? Various ideas of methods to solve this problems are appreciated !




Angle chase on $BPCH$ gets the job done. For example, it is  "obvious" that $\angle BHC = \angle BPC, \angle HBP = \angle HCP$. Alternatively, it is "obvious" that $BH  \parallel PC$, CH \parallel BF$. So, no need to "draw something more".

Why it is obvious that $BH // PC, CH // BF$ ? I think it need to be proved here ?

Obvious is in quotation marks because it requires a bit of work to figure it out. I agree it needs to be proved, and I leave that to you.


Yes, $BH \parallel PC$ is enough to prove that $BPCH$ is a parallelogram, because it is what $defines$ a $parallelogram$.
I don't know what is $analytic$ $geometry,$ but I can give you a very very simple proof. It goes like this:


Since $AP$ is the diameter of the circle, then $\angle ACP=90^\circ \implies PC \perp AC$, again since $H$ is the orthocenter of the triangle, so $BH \equiv BF\perp AC$, so, $$\boxed{BH \parallel PC}.$$
Similarly, $PB\perp AB,  \text{and},CH\equiv CE \perp AB \implies \boxed{PB\parallel CH}, $ thus, $BPCH$ is a parallelogram. $\square$


Your procedure is OK. Personally, I would have done the exact same way.

